# Kubernetes pull from insecure docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have stacked in this phase:

1. Have local docker insecure registry and some images in it, e.g. 192.168.1.161:5000/kafka:latest
2. Have kubernetes cloud cluster, for which I can access only via ~/.kube/config file, e,g. token.

Need to deploy below deployment, but kubernetes cannot pull images, error message:

> Failed to pull image "192.168.1.161:5000/kafka:latest": rpc error:
>   code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://192.168.1.161:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to
>   HTTPS client

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: port9094
    port: 9094
    targetPort: 9094
  selector:
    app: kafka
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      hostname: kafka
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: 192.168.1.161:5000/kafka:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always

      ports:
      - name: port9094
        containerPort: 9094
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: env

  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regsec
```

ON Kubernetes cluster I have created secret file "regsec" with this command:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsec  --docker-server=192.168.1.161 --docker-username=<name from config file> --docker-password=<token value from config file>

cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
        "auths": {},
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.06.0-ce (linux)"
        }

cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
      "insecure-registries":["192.168.1.161:5000"]
}

kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:05:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


    docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:09:54 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:07:56 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: kubectl get secrets

NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-8gwdd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         63d
default-token-ggqbj   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         46m
regsec                Opaque                                1         18m

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to go to each of your nodes, edit the file `/etc/default/docker.json` and add the following in it:

```
{
    "insecure-registries": ["192.168.1.161:5000"]
}
```

Comment: As I understand "  imagePullSecrets:" option is for not do edit /etc/default/docker on kubernetes side, but to make it understand about insecure docker registry... Am I right?

Comment: Yep - you need it both in Docker and Kubernetes since the docker API is just a wrapper for the Docker one. I edited my answer with how to do it for k8s too.

Comment: kubectl create secret docker-registry regsec --docker-server=http://192.168.1.161:5000 --docker-username=*** --docker-password=*** --insecure-skip-tls-verify[=true]
Error: unknown flag: --insecure-skip-tls-verify[

Comment: Oh, I pulled this from a fork of kubectl. Are you still getting the error after you add what's in my comment to /etc/default/docker?

Comment: Yes I have line `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 192.168.1.161:5000"` in mentioned file

Comment: Did you restart the docker daemon after applying this change?

Comment: systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: trying on both Centos 7 and ubuntu 18

Comment: @Neekoy if we don't have the node access, then we'll have to make registry secure and then use ImagePullSecrets ?

Comment: Is there a way to specify this in your deployment yaml? Or on the Secret?

Answer (score 3):

I used `minikube` for my Kubernetes cluster.

When I tried to `apply` a Pod with an image from my private docker registry (that is local, without authentication), the Pod didn't run and `describe` had a message indicating the repository wasn't reached (paraphrasing).

To fix this, I had to configure `insecure-registry` for the Docker daemon. According to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon), this can be done in two ways: as a flag passed to the `dockerd` command, or by modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (on Linux).

However, as I used `minikube` to create and configure the cluster and daemon, I instead followed the [`minikube` docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/#enabling-insecure-registries) to set the flag `--insecure-registry`. The complete command is:

```sh
minikube start --insecure-registry "DOMAIN_DOCKER_REGISTRY:PORT_DOCKER_REGISTRY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come to this thread over and over again trying to find the correct answer to get rid of certificates issues, without much success.

I finally solved the problem by installing the self signed certificate root on the system for all the kubernetes machines. That finally fixes the issue. On Ubuntu, you can import via:

```
sudo mv internal-ca.cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/internal-ca.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Keep in mind that if you have a certificate chain, it will require the root certificate, not the immediate certficate. You can check if the import worked by running:

```
openssl s_client -connect <YOUR REGISTRY HERE> -showcerts < /dev/null
```

You should see something like:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
```

as the response.

Answer (score 0):

for rancher 2.7 i found a solution to this problem
[here](https://docs.k3s.io/installation/private-registry)

In the /etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml file, add your config.

I wrote like this.

```
mirrors:
  image.bubot.ru:
    endpoint:
      - "https://192.168.1.39:5000"
configs:
  "192.168.1.39:5000":
    tls:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

helm doesn't know how to walk over http, so my register used a self-signed certificate.

for http

```
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "http://mycustomreg.com:5000"
```