# Kubernetes pull from local registry not working, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893120/kubernetes-pull-from-insecure-docker-registry) and created a secret as below.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsec --docker-server=192.168.56.106:5000 --docker-username=osboxes --docker-password=osboxes.org --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
```

And the deployment as below.

```
kubectl create deploy nginx1 --image 192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0
```

And edited it using

```
kubectl edit deploy nginx1
```

And added imagePullSecrets to it

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-21T10:23:23Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: nginx1
  name: nginx1
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "6872"
  uid: 0b6917f0-10ac-4206-82a8-c49ae8ffa2b3
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: todoapp
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsec
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-21T10:23:23Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-07-21T10:23:23Z"
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-21T10:23:23Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-07-21T10:28:36Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "nginx1-75df7fd466" is progressing.
    reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 2
  replicas: 2
  unavailableReplicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

But still getting below error.

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/Desktop$ kubectl get pods
    NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
    nginx-6799fc88d8-vvzjf    1/1     Running            0          19m
    nginx1-65d848d94f-dd4ck   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          12m
    nginx1-75df7fd466-kn5mf   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          6m50s

osboxes@osboxes:~/Desktop$ kubectl describe pod nginx1-75df7fd466-kn5mf
Name:         nginx1-75df7fd466-kn5mf
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         samples-control-plane/172.19.0.3
Start Time:   Wed, 21 Jul 2021 06:28:36 -0400
Labels:       app=nginx1
              pod-template-hash=75df7fd466
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.244.0.8
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx1-75df7fd466
Containers:
  todoapp:
    Container ID:
    Image:          192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-88clq (ro)
Conditions:

  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-88clq:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  73s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx1-75df7fd466-kn5mf to samples-control-plane
  Normal   Pulling    33s (x3 over 73s)  kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0"
  Warning  Failed     33s (x3 over 73s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0": failed to resolve reference "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.56.106:5000/v2/todoapp/manifests/1.0": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
  Warning  Failed     33s (x3 over 73s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    6s (x4 over 72s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0"
  Warning  Failed     6s (x4 over 72s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-13T02:40:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-21T23:01:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Adding docker insecure registry is not useful as the container runtime is not docker now.It is containerd.

/etc/default/docker.json

And for reference, I have setup the local container on a virtualbox VM and connecting to kubernetes on the same network using Host-only network ip address.

The setup of local registry is created using the steps mentioned in [link](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/setup-private-docker-registry/).

And the kubernetes was setup using [kind](https://linuxdiaryblog.blogspot.com/2021/07/deploy-kubernetes-inside-docker-using.html).

Answer (score 1):

##### cri-o

If you are using `cri-o` as Container Runtime Provider, docker settings are of no use. You would require to configure `cri-o` instead: https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o#configuration

Assuming you have `cri-o` installed on the host node, the official documentation recommends to have a `$HOME/.config/containers/registries.conf` file, or a global, `/etc/containers/registries.conf` file to configure registries in a runtime engine agnostic way.

The file structure spec is also documented: https://github.com/containers/image/blob/main/docs/containers-registries.conf.5.md

Example:

```
[registries.search]
registries = ['registry1.com', 'registry2.com']

[registries.insecure]
registries = ['registry3.com']

[registries.block]
registries = ['registry.untrusted.com', 'registry.unsafe.com']
```

##### containerd

`Containerd` does not seem to acknowledge the `/etc/containers/registries.conf` settings.

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md), The main config file `/etc/containerd/config.toml` can specify a registry config path as:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

And inside the path specified above (`/etc/containerd/certs.d`) create a directory for host (`docker.io`) and in it, create a `hosts.toml` file. That is `/etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml`:

```
server = "https://registry-1.docker.io"

[host."http://my-custom-registry:5000"]
  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve", "push"]
  skip_verify = true
  plain-http = true
```

For `my-custom-registry:5000` section you can also provide credentials as well as certificates.

And restart `containerd` daemon/service on the host.

Configuration file spec is here: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md

Comment: I didn'ttry this yet but it seems to add on each node. Is there anyway to update in the kubernetes api wiith any kubectl command or yaml file so that it will apply to all the nodes?

Comment: @uday, please let us know when you try this solution.

Comment: My mistake, sorry, the container runtime is containerd, not crio.

Comment: @uday Updated to cover `containerd` as well.

Comment: my registry is running on a netwrok machine let's say my image is 192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0 . So what should be the directory name and file entry for this?

Comment: @uday Directory name is usually after the "fallback" registry (`docker.io`), file name is always `hosts.toml` as per `crd` standard. The custom registries go as [sections] in the hosts file. In your case the file would contain IP `192.168.56.106`, in place of `my-custom-registry` part.

Comment: Updated containerd runtime as you metioned and created the deployment again. This time not showing any pods. And not showing any error also. Please see the log at this link.   https://pastebin.com/8brb3TvX

Comment: even with the containerd command inside. I am getting this error.

oot@uday-control-plane:/# ctr image pull 192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0
INFO[0000] trying next host                              error="failed to do request: Head \"https://192.168.56.106:5000/v2/todoapp/manifests/1.0\": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client" host="192.168.56.106:5000"
ctr: failed to resolve reference "192.168.56.106:5000/todoapp:1.0": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.56.106:5000/v2/todoapp/manifests/1.0": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Comment: @uday `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`, Try adding the line `plain-http = true` under the `skip-verify` line.

Comment: still same.and also is it skip-verify or skip_verify?

Comment: The official documentation has [this section](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md#bypass-tls-verification-example) which is an example for an `http` registry (and not `https`). Ensure the file is as in this example.