# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error") in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, docker-registry

I have already deployed a local registry which listens on `192.168.xx.xx:5000`.

In `/etc/hosts` I have added:

```
192.168.xx.xx my.local.registry
```

and using `sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json` I have added:

> { "insecure-registries":["my.local.registry:5000"] }

Then I pushed an image on it using:

```
sudo docker tag hello-world my.local.registry:5000/hello-world
sudo docker push my.local.registry:5000/hello-world
```

Everything works as excpected. In `https://my.local.registry:5000/v2/_catalog` I am able to see the pushed image:

> {"repositories":["hello-world"]}

In the next step, I wanted to create a pod, thus a Deployment which will be able to download the image from my local registry. Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: registry-test
  labels:
    app: registry-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: registry-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: registry-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry-test
        image: my.local.registry:5000/hello-world
```

I have generated my own certificate using:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout ./certs/tls.key -x509 -days 365  -subj "/C=GR/ST=./L=./O=./CN=my.local.registry" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:my.local.registry" -out ./certs/tls.crt
```

and then I created a folder `sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/my.local.registry:5000` where I put the newly created certificate using `sudo scp certs/tls.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/my.local.registry:5000/ca.crt`

Then I added `sudo cp certs/tls.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt` and finally I executed:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates 
sudo service docker restart
sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

However, when I apply the Deployment with `kubectl apply -f mytestDeployment.yaml` I get

> Failed to pull image "my.local.registry:5000:5000/hello-world": rpc
> error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image
> "my.local.registry:5000:5000/hello-world:latest": failed to resolve
> reference "my.local.registry:5000:5000/hello-world:latest": failed to
> do request: Head
> "https://my.local.registry:5000:5000/v2/hello-world/manifests/latest":
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of
> "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate
> authority certificate "my.local.registry:5000")

There are plenty of answers in SO regarding this matter, however I am not able to fix this.
Does anyone know what am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I am also using a DeamonSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: registry-ca
  namespace: ches
  labels:
    k8s-app: registry-ca
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: registry-ca
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: registry-ca
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry-ca-docker
        image: busybox
        command: [ 'sh' ]
        args: [ '-c', 'mkdir /etc/docker/certs.d/my.local.registry:5000 && cp /home/core/tls.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/my.local.registry:5000/ca.crt && exec tail -f /dev/null' ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etc-docker
          mountPath: /etc/docker/certs.d
        - name: ca-cert
          mountPath: /home/core
      - name: registry-ca-containerd
        image: busybox
        command: [ 'sh' ]
        args: [ '-c', 'cat /home/core/tls.crt > /home/core-containerd/ca.crt && exec tail -f /dev/null']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ca-cert
          mountPath: /home/core
        - name: etc-containerd
          mountPath: /home/core-containerd
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: etc-docker
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/docker/certs.d
      - name: ca-cert
        secret:
          secretName: ches-registry-secret
      - name: etc-containerd
        hostPath:
          path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

However the error persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545732/how-do-i-access-a-private-docker-registry-with-a-self-signed-certificate-using-k

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doen't. I have a DeamoSet like this.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did everything right setting up your private registry. However Kubernetes doesn't allow pulling images from insecure private registries (yes, a self-signed certificate is still considered "insecure").

I'm afraid you have to tell every Kubernetes node that your `my.local.registry` is either [an insecure registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893120/kubernetes-pull-from-insecure-docker-registry) or place the certificate file in every node (as described in the second link of Priyanka's answer).

A different option might be to create a certificate using letsencrypt, so it's signed by a known certificate authority, thus being "secure". But that limits the use of custom domain names.